# Plugin for Authentication & Authorization in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there any plugin for WordPress that  allow me to register users/visitors and to have them be able to only see certain pages and certain data with role to each user ?

I searched but i found membership plugin but it is closed now

Any another plugin ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `simple strict plugin` and this is the link `https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-restrict/` with explain how to use it